# VBA XML HTTP setrequest header in GET request based on previous getresponseheader (token) value

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, request-headers, response-headers

For a product scraping project I need to pass a value in the header of a GET request with XMLHTTP in VBA. The value / token that needs to be passed is extracted from a previous XMLHTTP GET request (getReponseHeader) and stored in a variable in VBA.

When passing the value with setRequestHeader in a PUT request the correct value is passed on correctly (when checking with a getReponseHeader afterwards). But when sending the value in a GET request it doesn't work (a different token is extracted).

By connecting the correct store information with the active session (by sending the token in the header) the specific price for a product can be extracted that is linked to the specific store. For the sample product the price of 1,87 is the one i need. When no store is linked to the session the price of 1,97 is extracted. This is why i need to send the header information with correct x-jumbo-token in the following GET requests.

Here is what i need to do:

- Extract a token (x-jumbo-token) from a first XMLHTTP request
- Save/store this token in a VBA variable (and send it in header together with all the following requests).
- Send a PUT request with some store information in a JSON body and send the x-jumbo-token also as a request header (store information is connected now to the session).
- Send a GET request to another URL (together with the session token in the header) to extract the product information for the correct store.

Here is is the code i currently have.

```
Sub GetJumboPriceXML()

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim JumboPrice As Double
Dim SKU_tag As String, SKU_url As String
Dim Jumbo_token As String
Dim Body As String

'sample product (MARS 225gr) --> price 1,97 (when no store is selected), 1,87 when correct store is linked (store id 3065, complexNumber 33164)
SKU_tag = "153501PAK"
SKU_url = "http://mobileapi.jumbo.com/v2/products/" & SKU_tag

'get the x-jumbo-token value from the configuration page
XMLReq.Open "GET", "http://mobileapi.jumbo.com/v2/configuration", False
XMLReq.send
'store in variable
Jumbo_token = XMLReq.getResponseHeader("x-jumbo-token")
Debug.Print Jumbo_token

send JSON body with store info together with x-jumbo-token in header to select correct store
Body = "{""id"":""3065"", ""complexNumber"":""33164""}"
XMLReq.Open "PUT", "http://mobileapi.jumbo.com/v2/users/me/homestore", False
XMLReq.setRequestHeader "x-jumbo-token", Jumbo_token
XMLReq.send (Body)
'check on response value of x-jumbo-token (is equal to the token I sent in header), all seems fine until this point
Debug.Print XMLReq.getResponseHeader("x-jumbo-token")

'send final request to product page and extract the price info
XMLReq.Open "GET", SKU_url, False
XMLReq.setRequestHeader "x-jumbo-token", Jumbo_token
XMLReq.send

JumboPrice = Split(Split(XMLReq.responseText, "prices"":{""price"":{""currency"":""EUR"",""amount"":")(1), "}")(0) / 100

'debug print product price > 1,97 is displayed instead of 1,87 (when the correct store is connected to the session).
Debug.Print JumboPrice
'x-jumbo-token from RepsonseHeader is different vs. the one I sent as header with the request.
Debug.Print XMLReq.getResponseHeader("x-jumbo-token")

End Sub
```

Any suggestions how i could pass the correct token in the subsequent GET request and extract the same x-jumbo-token in the getResponseHeader of the final request, and extract the correct price of 1,87?

Comment: I don't think your PUT is successful. I see no home store set.

Comment: @QHarr, thanks for your comment. I found some instructions on GitHub. https://github.com/bartmachielsen/SupermarktConnector/blob/master/Connector/JumboConnector.py  

Homestore should be set with a JSON object and PUT the (store) id and complexNumber to http://mobileapi.jumbo.com/v2/users/me/homestore 

for this example I just the fixed numbers for that, found in http://mobileapi.jumbo.com/v2/stores

Comment: Yeah... I have read those and ran through them comparing with your code. Doesn't make a difference but your JSON above should it be "{""id"":""3065"", ""complexNumber"":""33249""}"

Comment: @QHarr, yes i tried to include the "" but output remains the same... (different x-jumbo-token value).

Comment: Have you tried running via python and using session etc to maintain?

Comment: @Qharr, no sorry i'm not used to python at all, just learning VBA at the moment...

Comment: Well I hope you get the upvotes you deserve on a very good post.

Comment: You should note the following: _The AH makes use of [a] backend Rest-API that uses multiple security techniques to limit the data to only app users._ ..... _Basic authentication_  ..... _X-Digest_